# using coffee filters to filter home pressed olive oil

Tags: oil, olive, filtering

I have recently made some home pressed olive oil but it is quite cloudy and I wanted to filter it so it will keep longer and be a bit more pleasing to the palate and the eye.  I initially used a muslin (ham) bag in a steel colander over another steel bowl and weighted down with 70kg of gym weights to press.  I was wondering if it is effective to try running it through paper coffee filters to get rid of the fine particles?

Answer (score 4):

I have picked and processed hundreds of kilos of olives for oil. I store the cloudy oil in plastic water bottles in a dark cupboard and wait.  The sediment will fall and then you just drain off the clear oil. The remaining oil with the sediment in it I use for tools, hinges etc and other DIY uses.

Answer (score 2):

This site http://www.ehow.com/how_6673045_build-olive-oil-press.html
offers help.

> The raw oil can be filtered by through a coffee filter or fine mesh strainer to remove particulate matter. Filtered oil is less likely to burn during cooking.

Also check out this from http://www.ehow.com/how_7767059_make-oil-processing-equipment-home.html

> The oil is not ready to use after pressing. It needs to be cleaned and filtered. This requires only buckets, water, a funnel and coffee filters.

You may also want to read this before you decide if you really want to filter your oil.

> http://www.livestrong.com/article/523058-what-is-the-difference-between-filtered-unfiltered-olive-oil/

Comment: Have you done any of this? Sometimes the stuff on ehow can be a bit dodgy.

Comment: no .. i havent.. we dont home press olive oil.. But many sites suggest using cofee filter..

Comment: Coffee filters work great for filtering oil. Restaurants routinely use giant ones to filter deep fryer oil at the end of service. You'll lose a little to absorption, but the results will be very clear.

Comment: The livestrong link seems to be talking about heat-treating, not filtering through a coffee filter

Comment: Paper coffee filters? Cold oil will not go through that very fast... Still-warm deep fryer oil is another matter....

Answer (score 1):

Your other choice is to let gravity do its work. Let the oil rest until its particles sink to the bottom (probably a long time), after that extraction is simpler.

Comment: I don't think that is practical in realistic kitchens, and it would not help with particles small enough to remain suspended.